# Sublime Text: how to enable text replacement

Tags: sublimetext

In Notepad++ when I select a text and type something, it automatically deletes the selected text and replaces it with what I'm typing now, even if I'm typing quote characters.

In Sublime, if I type quote characters it inserts these around the text instead of replacing it.

Is it possible to have Sublime Text behave like Notepad++ and replace the text no matter what I'm typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the only thing you can do is set the "auto_match_enabled" property to false. You can find that setting in `Setting - Default` of SublimeText preferences.

```
// Controls auto pairing of quotes, brackets etc
    "auto_match_enabled": false,
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on your settings file (Preferences -> Settings User or Settings Default), set:

```
"auto_match_enabled": false,
```